# Accessing methods with the same name

Tags: java, class, object, methods

I have three classes that all have a method with the same name. My Main class has the method (called automatically when the user clicks their mouse):

```
public void mouseDown()
```

My second class is called Bed and has the method:

```
public void mouseDown()
```

My third class is called CreateBedButton and has the method (which returns a Bed object):

```
public Bed mouseDown()
```

I am able to access the Bed class' mouseDown method fairly easily from the mouseDown method in Main, but I have no idea how to indicate that I want to call the CreateBedButton class' mouseDown method. They all have no parameters, but when I call the Bed class' mouseDown method I access it through a Bed object I created using:

```
bed.mouseDown();
```

When I try just calling:

```
mouseDown();
```

from Main, it calls the Main method's mouseDown method again. is there any way that I can access all three methods/make it apparent which method I actually want to access??

Comment: call `.mouseDown()` to access the `Main` class' method. Call `bed.mouseDown()` to access the `Bed` class' method. Call `createRedButton.mouseDown()` to call the `CreateRedButton` class' method. This assumes that you have the variables `Bed bed = new Bed();` and `CreateRedButton createRedButton = new CreateRedButton()` declared.

Answer (score 0):

Call `.mouseDown()` to access the Main class' method. Call `bed.mouseDown()` to access the `Bed` class' method. Call `createRedButton.mouseDown()` to call the `CreateRedButton` class' method.

This assumes that you have the variables `Bed bed = new Bed();` and `CreateRedButton createRedButton = new CreateRedButton()` declared.

An example is below.

```
class Main {

    public void main(String [] args) { // Starting point of program
        Bed bed = new Bed();
        CreateRedButton createRedButton = new CreateRedButton();
        mouseDown(); // Calls Main's mouseDown();
        bed.mouseDown(); // Calls Bed's mouseDown(); 
        Bed catchingBed = createRedButton.mouseDown(); // Calls CreateRedButton's mouseDown(); - Which returns a Bed

        // Or you can even do this..
        CreateRedButton redButton = new CreateRedButton();
        Bed bed = redButton.mouseDown();
        bed.mouseDown();
    }
    public void mouseDown() {
        // Some code
    }
}
class Bed {

    public void mouseDown() {
        // Some code
    }
}
class CreateRedButton {
    public Bed mouseDown() {
        // Some code to return a Bed
    }
}
```